# Convert Oracle Datetime with more than 24 Hours

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have field V_Date (YYYYMMDD) & V_Time (HHMISS).

The problem, format time is not in HH24 but 30 Hours.

The data is: **20180307** & **313025**

Base on above data, I want to convert to normally as **20180308** & **073025**
So, I can convert to timestamp like below sql:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('20180308073025', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Not very clear as what this represents `313025`

Comment: Show some more examples of the data and the expected output in tabular format. Don't add them in the comments. Edit the question. No images please, only text format.

Comment: Funny... a manufacturing client of mine (years ago) asked me to code all the lot date logic for 30 hour days.  I thought it bizarre, but now I find they're not alone.  Very interesting!

Comment: http://articles.latimes.com/2012/mar/01/opinion/la-oe-krikorian-time-20120301

Comment: `31` doesn't fit in either 24 hours *or* 30 hours; anyway, your example shows that the hours merely extend across the next day; it's still a 24 hour clock, and you merely want to normalise the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the time value to the date value. But before you have to convert the time value to the amount of seconds. In Oracle a day have the value of 1. A half day (12 hours) is 0.5 and a second is 1/(24 * 60 * 60).

So here is an example:

```
WITH DS AS (
    SELECT 313025 AS V_TIME,
           20180307 AS V_DATE
      FROM DUAL
)
SELECT (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(V_TIME, 1, 2)) * 3600 
       + TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(V_TIME, 3, 2)) * 60 
       + to_number(substr(v_time, 5, 2))) / (24 * 60 * 60)
       + TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(V_DATE), 'YYYYMMDD') AS YOUR_DATE
  FROM DS
;
```

Hope ist helps.

Comment: As mentioned in question, the data is `20180307 & 313025` and output expected is `20180308 & 073025`. I atleast couldnot find any relevance. Not sure if your answer really solves this.

Comment: @XING as i understand 310725 is the time, 31 hours 30 minutes and 25 seconds. the result is the same as the expected result by the author.

Comment: Hi DirkNm, thank for your answer, I think the logic mus be same with us: TO_DATE('20180307','YYYYMMDD') + (1/24*((31 * 60 * 60) + (30 * 60) + 25)/3600). Anyway thank you I think no have Oracle function to define HH30 :D

Answer (score 2):

For convert time to second, values like "140:05:10" you can use below code:

```
SELECT (REGEXP_SUBSTR('140:05:10','[^:]+',1,1)*3600 ) +
(REGEXP_SUBSTR('140:05:10','[^:]+',1,2) * 60) + 
(REGEXP_SUBSTR('140:05:10','[^:]+',1,3)) sec from DUAL;
```

output=504310